# jmeter restful api get connection close , bad request and warning at report

Tags: jmeter

I tried to use Jmeter to run a simple GET API query. but Warning always returned.

The URI at result is correct.

I am not sure what else is wrong, please advise what is missing.

at tree report request body, which i see the GET endpoint correct

```
GET http://localhost:8015/api/items/drug

GET data:


[no cookies]
```

at tree report request header:

```
Connection: keep-alive
: 
: 
Host: localhost:8015
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_231)
```

Response data, Response Header

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 08:49:28 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: This is a limitation on Kestrel concurrent requests. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxconcurrentconnections?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-server-kestrel-core-kestrelserverlimits-maxconcurrentconnections)

Answer (score 0):

As per [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `400 Bad Request` response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
>
> **The client should not repeat this request without modification.**

It means that you're sending the request which is syntactically incorrect, check out your application logs, it might be the case it contains the details which might help getting to the bottom of the issue.

Most probably you're getting the error due to missing [request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), most probably [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) and/or [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). The headers can be passed using the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)

Comment: the GET endpoint does not need any header, i am using POSTMAN which no header need to be defined. is jmeter need to be specially configured? what should be the header for GET? i quickly added Accept application/json at header manager ,same warning bad request.

Comment: Most probably there is a typo somewhere in your script, i.e. space character in URL or something like this, cannot tell for sure unless I see the full test plan

Comment: nope. i copy the result in jmeter URI and paste to browser, it works. it is just simple ENDPOINT, nothing special that i will get them wrong. i suspect jmeter need to manually configure. its not straightforward like POSTMAN. searching this error in stackoverflow many asked the same but no solution. so jmeter is not a right tool to test load API?

Comment: JMeter is capable of sending the same HTTP requests as Postman or the real browser, the easiest way of generating the request is just recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by simply delete the HTTP Manager.
then now i got the green result.

not sure why. i will explore more.
so if anybody see the same, try not to use HTTP Manager.